# How to find user's country, state(region/county/province) and city in MVC application depending upon location from where he is accessing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC application, I want to display Country, Region and City of the user from where he is accessing the website. How can I fetch them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways. One is to ask the user to share his location with the remote server.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation

The other involves "guessing" using the remote ip address and some service like this:

http://freegeoip.net/

Comment: Another, commercial option: http://www.skyhookwireless.com/location-technology/sdk.php (I don't work for them). Another option is to use a sign in service like Facebook, and request this information from there.